# md-select and md-option with if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I am trying get value from md-option for example:

```
<md-select name="state" ng-model="currentUser.state" ng-change="selectChanged()" required>
                        <md-option value="Test">Test</md-option>
                        <md-option value="Test2">Test2</md-option>
                        <md-option value="Test3">Test3</md-option>
</md-select>
```

And I want to take

> value: Test3

```
 $scope.selectChanged = function(){
   if ($scope.currentUser.state=="Test3"){
      $scope.curr_date = new Date();
    }
  };
```

But it isn't work. How can I get value Test3 to set something if it selected.

Comment: Try to change `value` to `ng-value` in every option.

Comment: It should work - https://jsfiddle.net/L8f1jLfh

Comment: can't use ng-value cause I can't put it into datebase

Comment: @AseemGautam Thank you very much you saved me I lost about 2 hrs. Say it as answer so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. Have you defined your controllers correctly? I have made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L8f1jLfh/1/) with your code - it works.

Please post complete controller code as well.

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {    
    $scope.currentUser = {};
    $scope.currentUser.state = {};
     $scope.selectChanged = function(){
        if ($scope.currentUser.state=="Test3"){
            alert('yay!');
    }
  };     
})
```